# Load Images From Fiverr in TableView

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, sdwebimage

Hi i am making an application in Xcode and using swift for that. I am downloading images from Firebase and show them in the table view. There are some problems with that. But first i will show the code.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customCell", for: indexPath) as! FrontViewCell

    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

    //let whiteRoundedView : UIView = UIView(frame: CGRect(10, 8, self.view.frame.size.width - 20, 149))
    let whiteRoundedView: UIView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 8, width: self.view.frame.width - 20, height: 200))
    whiteRoundedView.layer.backgroundColor = CGColor(colorSpace: CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), components: [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.8])
    whiteRoundedView.layer.masksToBounds = false
    whiteRoundedView.layer.cornerRadius = 2.0
    whiteRoundedView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: -1, height: 1)
    whiteRoundedView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.2

    cell.contentView.addSubview(whiteRoundedView)
    cell.contentView.sendSubview(toBack: whiteRoundedView)

    //cell.categoryImageView.image = catImages[indexPath.row]
    //print("Product \(allCats[indexPath.row].name)")

    cell.categoryLabel.text = allCats[indexPath.row].name

    if let n = allCats[indexPath.row].name{
        con?.storage?.reference(withPath: "categories/\(n).png").data(withMaxSize: 10 * 1024 * 1024, completion: {
            data, error in
            if error == nil{
                let im = UIImage(data: data!)
                cell.categoryImageView.image = im
                cell.layoutSubviews()
            }
            else{
                print("Error Downloading Image \(error?.localizedDescription)")
            }
        })
    }
    return cell
}
```

So above is the code to set the images to an imageView in the cell. 
**Problems**

1. When i scroll down and then scroll up again, the images are different in the same cells.
2. The tableview scrolling is very laggy.

These are the problems. Please let me know how can i solve this?
I know of a library **SDWebImage** but i don't know how to download Firebase image with that library. Please help me through this problem. I am very exhausted by this problem. I have been trying to solve it for the last 20 hours without sleep but could not. Please let me know what i am doing wrong and how should i fix that. Thanks.

Comment: That has to do with the cache and where the images are stored. You should write a custom class for that.

Comment: I know this is about cashing the images but i don't want to create a mess by writing custom classes. Can you suggest me some API or anything like that, that will reduce my effort and time for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TableView is laggy because you are redownloading images all the time.

This is a caching issue.
As for the images being different in the same cell, you can change this just by resseting the image to nil, because cells are being reused, they are using a previous image, while the new one downloads.

But both of these issues would be fixed if you were to use some caching framework, for example, probably the best one out there is [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/).

If you don't wanna use a library for this. Here is the most basic implementation of caching images.

```
let imageCache = NSCache<AnyObject, AnyObject>()

extension UIImageView {

    func loadImageUsingCacheWithUrlString(_ urlString: String) {

        self.image = nil

        //check cache for image
        if let cachedImage = imageCache.object(forKey: urlString as AnyObject) as? UIImage {
            self.image = cachedImage
            return
        }

        //otherwise start the download
        let url = URL(string: urlString)
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in

            //there was an error with the download
            if error != nil {
                print(error ?? "")
                return
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {

                if let downloadedImage = UIImage(data: data!) {
                    imageCache.setObject(downloadedImage, forKey: urlString as AnyObject)

                    self.image = downloadedImage
                }
            })

        }).resume()
    }

}
```

Usage:

```
cell.categoryImageView.loadImageUsingCacheWithUrlString("your firebase url string")
```

EDIT: Yes, you can use this to download images that are stored in Firebase.

EDIT: This code will solve your issues, but memory management is not considered here, for a serious production app I would suggest looking into libraries dedicated to image caching.

EDIT: I just noticed that there is proper info on Firebase documentation , showing how it works with SDWebImage. Check it out: [SDWebImage + Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/download-files#downloading_images_with_firebaseui)

Comment: @Nesbojsa  Can SDWebImage download firebase images? How should i do that? Should i only have to provide the path of the image where it is stored in the firebase?

Comment: I've updated my answer, with basic implementation of caching, should you not want to use a library.
And yes, you can use this to get images that are stored in firebase.

Comment: Thank you @Nesbojsa for your effort and help.